# Dagger 2 generated files are unreachable

Tags: java, gradle, dagger-2

I perform the first use of Dagger 2 in my life and I think I encounter some issues that are considered insignificant by expirienced users and thus omitted in their guides.
So I created a simple absolutely empty class that does nothing, marked its constructor with `@Inject`, then created an interface with `@Component` annotation with method return type of which is my empty class. Then I invoked `gradlew build` and Dagger actually generated files that it must have generated. But these files are in build/generated/source/apt/main/com/warden/bot/ directory of my IDEA project whilst source code is in src/main/java/com/warden/bot/ directory of the project, so I can't use Dagger generated code in my program. Should there be a special setup for Dagger before use and what do I do now?

UPD
My build.gradle file is:

```
plugins {
    id "net.ltgt.apt" version "0.12"
}

version '2.0'

apply plugin: 'java'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}


dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.11'
    apt 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.11'
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
}

jar {
    manifest {
        attributes(
            'Class-Path': configurations.compile.collect { it.getName() }.join(' '),
            'Main-Class': 'com.warden.bot.Main'
    )
}
    from {
        configurations.compile.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it)     }
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you know that you can't use them in your program? The generated folders / sources are added to your source path just like your normal source files. If they are not, please include further information about your build (gradle, maven, ant, ...) the build script you use, how you run your app, etc

Comment: @DavidMedenjar I exactly know that I can't because when I put `DaggerBotComponent`, that must have been generated and thus be available in the program, IDEA immediately shows an error like "cannot resolve symbol "DaggerBotComponent".
Also I added my build.gradle to the body of the question

Comment: It seems that usage with IDE is documented: https://github.com/tbroyer/gradle-apt-plugin